# How to use function from other class

Tags: php, laravel, wordpress

Im trying to send a email with a list of companies that have the pending or waiting status.

This list is already collected in the following function:

```
public static function getCompaniesAwaitingCheck()
{
    $awaitingChangeApproval = self::getAwaitingChangeApproval();
    $awaitingPublication = self::getAwatingPublication();
    return array_merge($awaitingChangeApproval, $awaitingPublication);
}
```

Now I want to use that function to put in the email. I have made a separate class for this (`AdminPendingApprovalNotification.php`)

In there is the following function:

```
public function notifyPendingApproval()
{

    $dailyClaimMailTitle = get_field("daily_claim_overview_mail_title", 'options');
    $dailyClaimMailText = get_field('daily_claim_overview_mail_text', 'options');
    $dailyClaimMailAddress = get_field('daily_claim_overview_mail', 'options');

    $company = new Company();
    $pendingCompany = $company->getCompaniesAwaitingCheck();

    wp_mail(
        $dailyClaimMailAddress,
        ecs_get_template_part('views/email/template', [
            'title' => $dailyClaimMailTitle,
            'text' => $dailyClaimMailText, $pendingCompany,
        ], false),
        ['Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8']
    );

}
```

When I `dd($pendingCompany);` I get the error:`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Models\Model::__construct(), 0 passed in Emails/AdminPendingApprovalNotification.php on line 16 and exactly 1 expected`

line 16: `$company = new Company();`

Unfortunately can’t get it to work, I’m a beginner, some help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What **exactly** is not working? How is this related to Wordpress or Laravel?

Comment: What are the names of the two classes you've mentioned in your question?

Comment: @NicoHaase Using Wordpress & Laravel. When I ```dd($pendingCompany);``` I get the error:```PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Models\Model::__construct(), 0 passed in Emails/AdminPendingApprovalNotification.php on line 16 and exactly 1 expected ```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? You haven't shared line 16 of the given class

Comment: @NicoHaase line 16 is: ```$company = new Company();```

Comment: Ahd what have you tried to resolve the problem? `Too few arguments to function` sounds like you need to add any argument to the constructor (which you haven't shared, so nobody can tell you **which** arguments to add)

Comment: Try `Company::getCompaniesAwaitingCheck()`, but also read about how and when to use statics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method `getCompaniesAwaitingCheck` is static, so you should call it like:

```php
$pendingCompany = Company::getCompaniesAwaitingCheck();
```

An error occured because your `Company` class requires arguments in the `__construct` method, which you didn't provide.